# How could I display distanceMsg on each elements in AR.js?

Tags: javascript, geolocation, aframe, ar.js

I'm beginner of using AR.js; Could you please suggest me how can I display distanceMsg on each elements like above or below tag  (or could you please suggest me if there are other way to display it) in AR.js. Like this example [image](https://ibb.co/QMkSHd1)

I've found this on AR.js website, but I have no clue how can I display on each A-Frame tag like.

```
const distanceMsg = document.querySelector('[gps-entity-place]').getAttribute('distanceMsg');
```

Here are my script code

```
window.onload = () => {
    const scene = document.querySelector('a-scene');

    return navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (position) {

        loadPlaces(position.coords)
            .then((places) => {
                places.forEach((place) => {
                    const latitude = place.location.lat;
                    const longitude = place.location.lng;
                    const marker = place.location.mark;

                    const pin = document.createElement('a-image');
                    pin.setAttribute('gps-entity-place', `latitude: ${latitude}; longitude: ${longitude}`);
                    pin.setAttribute('look-at', '[gps-camera]');
                    pin.setAttribute('name', place.name);
                    pin.setAttribute('src', `${marker}`);

                    pin.setAttribute('scale', '2, 2');

                    pin.addEventListener('loaded', () => window.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('gps-entity-place-loaded')));

                    const clickListener = function(ev) {
                        ev.stopPropagation();
                        ev.preventDefault();

                        const name = ev.target.getAttribute('name');

                        const el = ev.detail.intersection && ev.detail.intersection.object.el;

                        if (el && el === ev.target) {
                            const label = document.createElement('span');
                            const container = document.createElement('div');
                            container.setAttribute('id', 'place-label');
                            label.innerText = name;
                            container.appendChild(label);
                            document.body.appendChild(container);

                            setTimeout(() => {
                                container.parentElement.removeChild(container);
                            }, 1500);
                        }
                    };

                    pin.addEventListener('click', clickListener);
                    
                    scene.appendChild(pin);
                });
            })
    },
        (err) => console.error('Error in retrieving position', err),
        {
            enableHighAccuracy: true,
            maximumAge: 0,
            timeout: 27000,
        }
    );
};
```

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

See the [fundamentals of adding entity's via script](https://aframe.io/docs/1.3.0/introduction/javascript-events-dom-apis.html#updating-position-rotation-scale-visible)

Looks like you need to Use A-frame register component instead of vanilla js. Very important to take this in and undertstand this and not try cherry-pick with this type of framework, otherwise, you risk using this out of context.

This is a finnicky framework where many things need to go right for location-based to work, so it's worth grabbing a coffee, taking some good time reading up.

Remember: Do not try to put A-Frame-related JavaScript in a raw  tag after  as we would with traditional 2D scripting. If we do, we’d have to take special measures to make sure code runs at the right time. See [Running content scripts at the right time](https://aframe.io/docs/1.3.0/core/scene.html#running-content-scripts-on-the-scene)